# Get data from cookie and set the language

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I want to get data from cookie and set language according to that data in one method. After that, I want to set current language and write another method for it. I am beginner at mvc 4 so i couldn't decide how to do. Thanks for helps. These are methods what i should write. I tried to write something;

```
private void InitLanguage()
{
     HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
     cookie = Request.Cookies["MyCookie"];
     if (cookie != null)
     {

     }
     else
     {             
     }
}
public void SetCurrentLanguage(String languageCode)
{

}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is? Do you want to read and write cookies or set the language?

Comment: I want to read cookies and according to that data i want to set the language

Comment: You can't just *set the language*. Computers can't translate text. This isn't possible.

Comment: By "set the language" I'm assuming you're setting some value that your program is using to determine the user's preferred language? We can't really help with setting that value because we don't know what it is or how your program implements it. You'll need to show us what the possible values of `languageCode` are and what your program does with them.

Comment: Yes user's preferred language should be used. languagecode = "tr-TR"
languagecode = "en-EN"

Answer (score 5):

Not clear what your requirements are but this is how to set a cookie

```
    HttpCookie cookieTemp = new HttpCookie("cookieTemp");
    cookieTemp.Value = "data in cookie";
    cookieTemp.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
    cookieTemp.Secure = true;
    cookieTemp.Shareable = false;

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookieTemp);
```

and this is how you read a cookie

```
var cookieValue = Request.Cookies("cookieTemp").Value;
```

if you want to check if a cookie is set or not check the value of the cookie if empty or not...